# C#: Oracle.DataAccess batch read

Tags: c#, oracle, batch-processing

Oracle drivers for .NET (assembly Oracle.DataAccess) don't have much documentation, so where can I read about batch reads? Or maybe someone can provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use OracleBulkCopy class.
Documentation is available here http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/E10927_01/bulkcopy.htm
It is an analogue for SqlBulkCopy class which is described in MSDN library pretty well.